# Getting current page type in model?

Tags: magento2.3, model

**Magento 2.3.4**

Is it somehow possible to get the current page in a model? I am using some sort of page speed optimizer and want to disable some of its features on the product page. I checked the code and the place to do that would be in a model class.

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start looking in the page Request.

For example `$this->getRequest()->getFullActionName()` might give you what you need.

On a product page this will result in: `catalog_product_view`

Comment: `$this->request->getFullActionName();` did the trick